# Java with Randoms Number

Tags: java, random

I'm a beginners with Java, and I have a problem about generating random numbers.

Here's what I wrote :

```
    int a = 1;
    // 0 to 10
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    int shoot1 = random.nextInt(11);
    int shoot2 = random.nextInt(11);


    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots " + shoot1);
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots " + shoot2);
    System.out.print("\nCHALLENGER SCORE: " + (shoot1 + shoot2));
```

Is there a way to generate two different numbers for shoot without having `shoot1` and `shoot2`? Is there a way to have one variable but generate two different numbers? When I use one variable it always give me the same number for both of the printed lines. Thank you!

Comment: When you want print two values and calculate the sum of both, there is no way around having at least two variables.

Comment: For one variable you could use a single array of 2 elements.

Comment: @RamblinRose that’s still having two variables, just with a different syntax.

Comment: Also don't use `SecureRandom` unless you're doing cryptography.  The regular `Random` is fine for games and such.

Comment: Sorry guys, i still dont understand how to do it. If someone can show me as an example it will be perfect for me to learn. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Whats wrong with having 2 variables?

Comment: Because after i need to use it again for others shoots, i'm gonna have to declare shoot3, shoot4, shoot5 etc. I need one single variable but they give  differents randoms numbers.

Comment: If you need to use the old values, then save them in a list and just access what you need via indices.

Comment: Please use Random rather than SecureRandom. Random has a nextInt() function that works like you think it does.

Comment: You could use a single variable, but you'd have to change the value with a new call to random after you did the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Lists.  This may help you solve your problem.

```
Random r = new Random();
List<Integer> shots = new  ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int shot = r.nextInt(11);
    System.out.println("Saving " + shot + " to List");
    shots.add(shot);
}

for (int s : shots) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

`Lists` are pretty fundamental to programming in Java.  You may want to check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more on this and other essential topics.